# Using ASM to load a file into memory?

Tags: assembly, nasm

i'm working on a small ASM program that needs to load another flat binary from
the disk/floppy/hdd w/e, and then start executing it. i can't seem to figure out how to scan
the local folder, or system for a file say main.bin, and then jump to the *main:* part of the code.

```
so for example we have a small file called main.bin, which is a 
compiled flat binary of nasm code. there is a label called main:
what i need to do is find the file main.bin and load into memory 
at address 0x0500, then jmp/give control to the loaded program and
have it start working at the main: label in the code.
```

if anyone can help me with this, it would be appreciated. thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details will depend on your hardware architecture and on your file system. Can you give us some more details?

Sounds like you're developing your own operating system. Particularly since you've tagged your question with "bootloader". Or are you hoping to do this within some other operating system?

Comment: not an OS, just a working boot-loader. also my hardware is an Intel core duo processor, with 2.66 ghz, 4 gb RAM, windows Vista, it is also 32 bit.

Comment: OK, well that's a different story. You will probably want to call an INT 13 function and let your BIOS take care of reading from the disk for you. You will need to store your bootsector at a specific location on the disk and use a specific format so you know where to jump in your flat binary (labels are just for humans, so they won't show up in the machine code). osdever.net has some good tutorials on this sort of thing, if you haven't seen that yet. You will probably also want to get a copy of vmware or something for testing and debugging.

Comment: thanks, i use qemu as a testing environment. great advice. however, could you show me a small example, i have trouble with the actual implementation, thanks if you do. but still thanks for advice.

Comment: For Intel IA-32 you'll find plenty of help in places like osdever.net as nw suggests, and also in alt.os.development, aodfaq.wikispaces.com and others. How far have you progressed with your bootloader? If you're right at the start then it's easiest to write your boot sector and main.bin to some fixed sectors in a floppy image, then use John Fine's rawrite.exe (or similar) to write it to a real floppy disk. Then use BIOS int 13h to read it, as nw says. Do you know about the bootloader start address at 0x0000:07e0 (check this detail) and the signature in the last two bytes, etc?

Comment: Intel used to make their developer manuals available for free, but I don't know whether they still do that - check out their website and look for "IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual".

Comment: yes, i know about where it is loaded into memory, as well as about the signature, however gaining access to a floppy is difficult since none of the computers i have have a floppy drive, so would it possible to write a main.bin, and a boot.bin, then load them into a qemu img file in order? if it is great, if it's not, then i may have to find some other alternative, but thanks for the help mate. (^.^)

Comment: I'm confident it's possible. I haven't used Qemu, but here's what I do in bochs: write boot.bin and main.bin to fixed sectors in a raw floppy disk image, then configure bochs to boot from that image.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from user land without making a system call. You also won't know where 'main' is on a flat binary (an object file would be a different story).

Comment: oh ok then, thanks for responding. just wondering if anyone else may have a different solution